# Output percentage in chart js label in a donut chart

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, chart.js

Im using chart js in my portfolio dashboard to track my visitors. This specific chart is tracking visits per page. Im doing this with express and mongodb. Everything works except i cant see the actual percentage, only how many visitors..

```
async function renderPageVisitDonutChart() {
    const statsData = await fetchData();

    if (statsData.pageVisitCounts) {
        const pageNames = statsData.pageVisitCounts.map(item => item[0]);
        const visitCounts = statsData.pageVisitCounts.map(item => item[1]);

        const ctx = document.getElementById('myDonutChart');

        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: pageNames,
                datasets: [{
                    data: visitCounts,
                    borderColor: '#000000',
                    backgroundColor: ['#2bd890', '#d2f00e', '#33e7f3', '#fd650f'],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                        labels: {
                            color: 'white',
                            font: { family: 'system-ui' }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Page Visits',
                        color: 'white',
                        font: { family: 'system-ui' }
                    }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var currentValue = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                            var total = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
                                return previousValue + currentValue;
                            }, 0);
                            var percentage = ((currentValue / total) * 100).toFixed(2);
                            return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ': ' + percentage + '%';
                        }
                    }
                },
                font: {
                    family: "'system-ui', '-apple-system', 'BlinkMacSystemFont'",
                    color: 'white'
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ive tried to add this to the tooltips but it didnt work.
Do i need the datalabel plugin for this?

```
tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var currentValue = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                            var total = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
                                return previousValue + currentValue;
                            }, 0);
                            var percentage = ((currentValue / total) * 100).toFixed(2);
                            return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ': ' + percentage + '%';
                        }
                    }
                },
```

I would really like your help with this. Please come with suggestions or other post that i can read becuase i cant find anything in chart js docs.

Comment: Would be great if you can attach sample data in the question. Thanks.